# What is the stuff hardened on an old flyback transformer?

Tags: flyback, repair, restoration

I am restoring some vintage old Mac computers with the integrated CRT display. These have a flyback transformer on their analog board. Part of this device is some hardened brown/orange material at the top that is solid and crumbly after 30+ years. It seems to have secured the bracket part in place as it passes through the central cylinder part.

Can anyone tell me what this material is/was, what job it was doing, and how to replace/refresh it when the system is intended to go back into use? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Very often the high-voltage diode was included in this additional material. You have a teardown analysis [here](https://www.angelfire.com/oh3/ebjoew/Flyback.html).

Comment: Perhaps corona dope? or simply gap-filling glue.